# Nothing installed after 'Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1'

Tags: android, sdk, platform

Not able to install Android SDK Platform on Windows XP. Nothing installed after a long download. Please guide if it is XP issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you started the Android SDK and AVD Manager from Eclipse, try exiting Eclipse and going into the SDK Folder. Run the update using the 'setup.exe' located there. I found that occasionally XP cannot move some of the old SDK files and will get hung since they are still in use by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, and found that it was about my network problem, The file didn't get downloded, I fix the network and things gets installed.

The problem is the Android manager didn't say why it can't install the API, there should be some message if the file didn't get downloaded properly..